# Emacs on Mac OS X Lion - what about the Ctrl and Alt touch?

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-lion

How can I hold Ctrl and arrow key up/down to move fast in my code? Because this is a shortcut in OS X.

How can I use alt (meta) touch? Emacs doesn't recognize option or command key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Control key shortcuts, you're probably best off using the Keyboard section of the System Preferences to disable any Ctrl+Arrow shortcuts. I changed all the Control key system shortcuts to use Control, Option and Command together, which is easy enough to hit (particularly on a full-size keyboard) while being much less likely to conflict with emacs.

As for the Meta key, if you are using terminal emacs, you may just have to put up with slightly poor modifier key support. (I've found a number of shortcuts to simply not work, even after playing with the terminal preferences. The terminal system is just slightly limited, it seems.) The easiest solution is to use the Esc prefix key instead of Meta - so instead of holding Meta and tapping the key, you tap Esc, and then tap the key. So for `M-x`, say, you would type `ESC x`. This is sometimes annoying (e.g., `M-f` and `M-b` aren't so convenient any more...), but it certainly does work.

If you can, I recommend switching to the GUI version of OS X emacs, which has none of these problems.

Comment: For the control key, I try what you said, but it appear that doesn't work. I tried :
-deactivate ctrl key
-deactivate ctrl combinaison shortcut keys.

Thank you for ESC tip. What do you mean by "GUI version of OS X emacs" ? What is the name of the program ?

Answer (score 2):

To make the option key work:
In the terminal settings '**CMD-,**' click '**Profiles -> Keyboard -> Use Option as a modifier key**'.